# Puppet: How to autorequire a define type?

Tags: puppet, custom-type

I am using Puppet 4 and need to autorequire a define type within my custom type. I am not able to get it working. Autorequiring another custom type works perfectly.

```
define foo::bar(...) {
   ...
}
```

And let us create a specific resource:

```
foo::bar { 'test' :
   ...
}
```

In my custom type I am using:

```
 autorequire('foo::bar') { 'test' }
```

I get no error, but the execution order is wrong. Is there no way to autorequire a define type?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no. See https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-5360 where this feature has been proposed.